# what is the time complexity of el.classList.remove in javascript

Tags: javascript

Does javascript store the classes in like a HashMap where there is constant lookup time or like an ArrayList where it lookup time is linear ?

This is because I use Tailwind CSS (where we give like 50 classes on average to an element) and I also to rapidly add and remove classes on DOM events.

So I'm just wondering if the app's performance will take a hit and also I'm curious on how Javascript method's [native code] works internally

Comment: If you have to add 50 classes to an element, then your own developer performance takes a hit before anything else ;) And on a more serious note: Did you run performance tests in your browser? The DOM specification mostly defines *behaviour*, not implementation. In this case, it only specifies that `classList` is an ordered set. Browsers are free to choose their own implementation.

Comment: `.classList` returns a [DOMTokenList](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#domtokenlist) and here are the details of its [remove](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-domtokenlist-remove) method

Comment: Anyways so since it is OrderedSet, the implementation has to be constant time lookup. Isn't it ? No matter how you implement acc. to the definition of a Set, the API calls for O(1) lookup

Comment: Having 50 properties in a CSS file would allow reuse, having 50 classes on an element does not. "*since it is OrderedSet, the implementation has to be constant time lookup*" – No. The generic concept of a Set does not say anything about time complexity. It is an implementation detail.